# Cancel operation with caching files

Tags: swift

I have AVPlayer and array of song links, also I have a buttons skip/previous.
In my task I have to download and cache file before playing it. I did it on completions, but problem is if I skipping songs fast, completion handler in startPlayer() calls a lot of times or some tracks stops to download at all

func with url of the song

```
func startPlayer(urlString: String) {
        
        trackCache.loadAudio(url: url) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                self.playerToggle(play: self.isPlaying)
            case .failure:
                self.delegate?.didCatchNetworkError()
            }
        }
 }
```

load song if it is not in the cache

```
func loadAudio(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> ()) {
        if !savedFiles.contains(where: { $0.key == url }) {
            downloadSong(url: url) { [weak self] result in
                guard let self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    self.trackDownloaded(url: url, completion: completion)
                default: break
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.trackDownloaded(url: url, completion: completion)
        }
    }
```

downloaded track

```
private func trackDownloaded(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> ()) {
        saveFileToDirectory(url: url) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let success):
                completion(.success(success))
            case .failure(let failure):
                completion(.failure(failure))
            }
        }
    }
```

save to the directory

```
private func saveFileToDirectory(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
        let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let audioFileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent + ".mp3")
        do {
            let data = self.savedFiles[url]
            try data?.trackData.write(to: audioFileURL)
            completion(.success(audioFileURL))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
```

who can help me to improve my code? Or what should I use to improve it?